Definition of multiplication of/with Ideals
Let $R$ be a ring with identity (not necessarily commutative) and $\mathfrak a\subseteq R$ an ideal in it. Consider the quotient ring $R/\mathfrak a$. The multiplication of two cosets $a+ \mathfrak a, b+\mathfrak a\in R/\mathfrak a$ is defined to be:
$$(a+ \mathfrak a)\cdot(b+\mathfrak a) = (a\cdot b)+\mathfrak a$$
While for groups it is possible to justify this type of definition via the conjugation operation and normality of the subgroup used to form the quotient group, I am having more difficulties to do the same with unitary rings, namely with the same notation as above:
$$(a+ \mathfrak a)\cdot(b+\mathfrak a) = a\cdot b+a\cdot\mathfrak a + \mathfrak a \cdot b+ \mathfrak a\cdot \mathfrak a$$
since $a\cdot\mathfrak a,\mathfrak a\cdot b,\mathfrak a\cdot \mathfrak a\subseteq \mathfrak a$ and I have not been able to group all the remaining terms using the symbol $\mathfrak a$ into a single "full" $\mathfrak a$ so far. Can somebody please help?

I take it you’re not assuming the ideal is two-sided?

Well, actually I might also be doing that: I essentially wrote my question this way to ensure that it were clear "what is where". I think the definition i have it in practice the one you are referring to.

A typesetting remark: using \mathfrak for ideals makes the question harder for me to follow. The symbols $\mathfrak{a}$ and $a$ look too similar, for instance.

@JW I don't know whether $b$ and $\mathfrak b$ or $c$  and $\mathfrak c$ also look too similar to you, but it is common to write ideals using the \mathfrak font, so it's worth examining the letters in this font closely enough to be able to recognize them as being distinct from italic letters. I used to be bothered by $\mathfrak P$ (P), thinking it was $\mathfrak B$ (B), but with experience this  stopped being an issue.

How do you get your second displayed equation? $\mathfrak a$ is not an element of $R$. The distributive law only applies to elements of $R$.

@KCd Thanks for the remarks. I know \mathfrak for ideals is fairly common and your advice is good. That said, I'd still prefer another way of writing them that is clearer to distinguish at a glance.

@KCd I've noticed that $I$ and $J$ are also commonly used for ideals.

@mr_e_man I think it was a naive attempt, now after a while I understood the thing, as KCd tried to explain me. As you pointed out, that thing there doesn't have a reason to be there.

When dealing with a noncommutative (well, not necessarily commutative) ring, you want to speak $\mathfrak a$ to be a two-sided ideal rather than merely being "an ideal": left ideals, right ideals, and two-sided ideals need not be the same thing and you don't get a ring structure in a nice way when taking the quotient by a left or right ideal that is not two-sided.
When $\mathfrak a$ is a two-sided ideal in $R$, you have shown that any element in $a + \mathfrak a$ and any element in $b + \mathfrak a$ have a product that lies in $ab + \mathfrak a$. That allows us to define the product $(a + \mathfrak a)(b + \mathfrak a)$ to be $ab + \mathfrak a$. There is no ambiguity in this definition.
By not being able to collect all the terms "into a single full $\mathfrak a$ so far" I think you mean that you are bothered by the fact that such products of elements in the two cosets may not fill up the entire coset $ab + \mathfrak a$. That doesn't matter.  We are aiming to make a definition of multiplication and declaring that $(a + \mathfrak a)(b + \mathfrak a) := ab + \mathfrak a$ is well-defined, so we proceed with this definition. It is irrelevant that you can't necessarily obtain all elements in $ab + \mathfrak a$ as products $xy$ with $x \in a + \mathfrak a$ and $y \in b + \mathfrak a$. The key point is that all such products $xy$ lie in a single coset, so we can define that coset to be the product of the original two cosets and go on developing ring theory.
When $R$ is commutative the same "problem" occurs, even in the simplest case $R = \mathbf Z$. You usually won't get all elements in $ab + m\mathbf Z$ to be products $xy$ where $x \in a + m\mathbf Z$ and $y \in b + m\mathbf Z$. Consider $m = 10$, so $\mathfrak a = 10\mathbf Z$. Define multiplication in $\mathbf Z/10\mathbf Z$ by $(a + 10\mathbf Z)(b + 10\mathbf Z) := ab + 10\mathbf Z$, so
$$
(3 + 10\mathbf Z)(7 + 10\mathbf Z) = 21 + 10\mathbf Z = 1 + 10\mathbf Z
$$
and the coset $1 + 10\mathbf Z$ contains infinitely many primes, such as $11$, $31$, $41$, $61, \ldots$, and none of these will ever be $xy$ where $x \in 3 + 10\mathbf Z$ and $y \in 7 + 10\mathbf Z$.
When I was a student, this issue bothered me when I first saw it (in the setting of commutative rings). Then I realized that there is no logical problem with the definition of multiplication of cosets. The problem is just a psychological one of expectations: we are reasoning by analogy with addition of cosets and are just expecting more to happen than what really happens. Instead, we should consider it an accident in the additive setting that the pairwise sums $x + y$ with $x \in a + \mathfrak a$ and $y \in b + \mathfrak a$ fill up all of $a + b + \mathfrak a$. All that really matters when defining operations on cosets by operating on coset representatives is that the results made with different representatives of the same cosets are contained in the same new coset. We don't need the results to "fill up" the new coset.
The same kind of "problem" occurs when defining the sum and product of ideals in a commutative ring: for sums we can set
$$
\mathfrak a + \mathfrak b := \{\alpha + \beta : \alpha \in \mathfrak a, \beta \in \mathfrak b\}
$$
since the right side really is an ideal. However, the set of all products
$$
\{\alpha\beta : \alpha \in \mathfrak a, \beta \in \mathfrak b\}
$$
is generally not an ideal since it is not closed under addition. Therefore we define
$\mathfrak a\mathfrak b$ to be the smallest ideal containing all products $\alpha\beta$ where $\alpha \in \mathfrak a$ and $\beta \in \mathfrak b$. The set of products already absorbs multiplication, so to make an ideal we just force additive closure by using all possible finite sums of products $\alpha\beta$:
$$
\mathfrak a\mathfrak b := \left\{\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i\beta_i : n \geq 1, \alpha_i \in \mathfrak a, \beta_i \in \mathfrak b\right\}.
$$
This definition of multiplication of ideals is certainly more involved than addition of ideals, but it is the minimum we need to have a useful product operation: $\mathfrak a\mathfrak b$ is the ideal generated by all products $\alpha\beta$ where $\alpha \in \mathfrak a$ and $\beta \in \mathfrak b$.  And watch out: although addition and multiplication of ideals in a commutative ring are both commutative and associative operations with respective identities $(0)$ and $(1)$ and multiplication distributes over addition, this does not make the set of ideals into a ring: there are no additive inverses!  Adding two ideals always leads to an ideal containing the original two ideals, so you'll never be able to add a nonzero ideal to any ideal and get the zero ideal $(0)$.

I would also add a comment that quotient rings are not at all about cosets. I am kind of hesitant to post this as an answer on my own since it's a duplicate anyway.

Well, first of all, thank you for your long answer. While I was reading your answer I had the impression that my point got a little bit misunderstood, although the fact that the points you were making are certaintly valid and the exposition very clear and well cooroborated by the example. I wouldn't say to be much bothered by the fact that "the products don't make up the ideal", in fact I would have cited the same result you added about the fact that the product of the ideals being "the ideal of the set of products", what bothers me most is rather that (in my second... [see new comment]

[see old comment] ... equation) the term $a\cdot\mathfrak a + \mathfrak a \cdot b+ \mathfrak a\cdot \mathfrak a$ should (in my current understanding) be equal to $\mathfrak a$, as algebraic structure is "dressed" upon set-theoretical objects fist of all and one would need at least to preserve the set-theoretical equality. So if those terms wouldn't add up to $\mathfrak a$, we would be braking a "fundamental" properity of set-theory, upon which those concept and objects are built.

Why do you think $a\mathfrak a + {\mathfrak a}b + \mathfrak a\mathfrak a$ should be equal to $\mathfrak a$? I have never heard anyone expect that to happen. And do you see a similar phenomenon happening or not happening with addition of cosets?

@MartinBrandenburg saying "quotient rings are not at all about cosets" goes against the way students are first introduced to quotient rings.  It seems analogous to saying derivatives are not at all about limits of Newton quotients (the way we all first learn about derivatives even though that viewpoint has to be abandoned to extend derivatives to the multivariable setting). When you learn more advanced math, the initial way you learned something may no longer be the right way to think about it, but it's not reasonable to say the initial way is "not at all" how to think about it.

@KCd I'll try to motivate the case of groups first: for a $G$ and a normal subgroup of his, $N$, one has: $(xN)(yN)=x(yNy^{-1})(yN) = xyNN = xyN$, since $N$ contains the $e$ element of $G$ (so $NN = N$). In this cases we have never seen the cosets as else than $\textbf{sets}$ among which one defines certain operation, also back to ideals, I see for instance an element of $R/\mathfrak a$ of the form $r+\mathfrak a$ to be the set ${r+a: a\in \mathfrak a}$. Hence if $(a+\mathfrak a)(b+\mathfrak a) = ab+\mathfrak a$, then also the cosets need to be equal. I hope it is readable and makes sense.

@MartinBrandenburg maybe there is something deeply rooted in the theory that I am missing. But set-wise if we want to keep the equality of the cosets, at least, I think that $a\cdot\mathfrak a + \mathfrak a \cdot b+ \mathfrak a\cdot \mathfrak a$ shouldn't be different from $\mathfrak a$.

The cosets do not need to be equal. What bothers you turns out to be  exactly the issue I wrote about in my answer: if you have a new binary operation on cosets defined by applying some prior binary operation on coset representatives and using the coset containing all those operated representatives, then all that matters for the coset operation to make sense is that all operations on representatives from the two cosets have values in a common coset. It is not necessary that those values entirely fill up the coset they are commonly contained in. The case of quotient groups is a happy accident.

@KCd thank you again for the nice answer, I will take some more time to restudy the whole thing and your kind answer more in details. Thank you for your time.

@KCd Got it. Thanks :)
